# Deno serve imported from std/http/server.ts is not async iterable?

Tags: deno

Here's the entirety of my .js file:

```ts
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std/http/server.ts"

let server = serve({ port: 4000 })
for await (const req of server){
  console.log('literally anything')
}
```

I'm using entirely code which i've seen multiple other people run without issues, and i have myself ran similar for loops before on this same machine. I don't understand what i broke, or if i'm importing the wrong thing, i have no idea what the right thing is. I'm on Local Deno version 1.18.1, the path is the one i get from the deno.land site, and the error i get when i try deno run --allow-net on that code is:

> error: Uncaught TypeError: server is not async iterable
> for await (const req of server){
> at file:///H:/proj/testapp/serveHTTP.js:4:25

Answer (score 3):

The return type of `serve` *used to be* `Server` (which is async iterable) up until `std` version `0.106.0`: here's [a link](https://deno.land/std@0.106.0/http/server.ts#L299) to that version of `serve`. That's probably why you've seen examples using it that way.

Starting in version `0.107.0` of `std`, the signature of `serve` [changed](https://deno.land/std@0.107.0/http/server.ts#L559) to accept a `Handler` instead (and return `Promise<void>`).

Here's [a link](https://doc.deno.land/https://deno.land/std@0.123.0/http/server.ts/%7E/serve) to the documentation for the current version of `serve` (from `std@0.123.0`), and here's an example of how to use it:

`so-70963882.ts`:

```ts
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.123.0/http/server.ts";

function requestHandler (request: Request): Response {
  const data = {
    url: request.url,
    headers: Object.fromEntries([...request.headers].sort()),
  };

  console.log(data);
  const body: BodyInit = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
  const headers = new Headers([['content-type', 'application/json']]);
  const init: ResponseInit = {headers};
  return new Response(body, init);
}

const ac = new AbortController();
serve(requestHandler, { port: 4000, signal: ac.signal });

const responseText = await (await fetch('http://localhost:4000')).text();
console.log(responseText);
ac.abort();
```

In the console:

```
deno run --allow-net ./so-70963882.ts
{
  url: "http://localhost:4000/",
  headers: {
    accept: "*/*",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, br",
    host: "localhost:4000",
    "user-agent": "Deno/1.18.1"
  }
}
{
  "url": "http://localhost:4000/",
  "headers": {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, br",
    "host": "localhost:4000",
    "user-agent": "Deno/1.18.1"
  }
}
```

> You should always use versioned URLs — which are more likely to "be immutable" (provide idempotent responses) — for imported modules whenever possible.

Comment: That was not it. It does it in a fresh file, too, and the error is the same, even when i specify v 0.123.0 of std:
https://i.imgur.com/DHYEQtN.png

I was hoping it was a cache issue, too, just didn't know how to work with it. Any other ideas, per chance? :l

Comment: @domi I updated my answer. Does that work for you?

Comment: i appreciate it. I had something very similar working, which i more recently replaced with an implementation of the 3rd pty tool Abc, because it's a lot more concise and readable. So, the job was getting done either way, but what i was trying to get at is that the serve import cannot be used as an async iterable on my end. I honestly think whatever is causing the error must be in my Deno version, and not in my code. This doesn't seem to be a problem for anyone else. But i can't use that kind of for loop as a listener. Since my local version is updated, i'm just out of ideas.

Comment: @domi I updated my answer again to explain more about how the function signature of `serve` has changed between versions.

Comment: thank you for clarifying! I'm relieved to know that it's not a local issue i created somehow. I must have been using a versioned import the previous time i used the shorthand loop. Appreciate your time in explaining!